# somebody explain to me how this query works step by step?

Tags: sql, database, select

I don't yet understand this SQL statement:

```
select FIRST_NAME 
from EMPLOYEES e 
where DEP_ID != (select DEP_ID 
                 from EMPLOYEES 
                 where e.MANAGER_ID = EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

Comment: Its a corelated subquery, for every row in the outer query , the Select in the where will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your query as:

```
select e.FIRST_NAME 
from EMPLOYEES e 
where e.DEP_ID <> (select e2.DEP_ID 
                   from EMPLOYEES e2
                   where e.MANAGER_ID = e2.EMPLOYEE_ID
                  );
```

This does not functionally change the query but it qualifies all column references and uses `<>` which is the traditional SQL operator for not equals.

What this query is doing is returning all employees whose department is not the same as their managers department.

How does it do this?  The subquery is a *correlated* subquery.  For each row in `employee`s the subquery returns the department id of the manager.

The `where` clause then checks whether or not it matches the employee's manager.

Answer (score 0):

This `subquery` will get the Manager's departments.

```
select DEP_ID from EMPLOYEES where e.MANAGER_ID = EMPLOYEE_ID
```

So the main query will just get the employees that not managers.

```
select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEES e where DEP_ID != (Managers dept_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's finding the employees who are not under a particular manager.
Let's see the inner part first:

```
select DEP_ID from EMPLOYEES where e.MANAGER_ID = EMPLOYEE_ID
```

This will fetch the department under particular manager
Now the outer part:

```
select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEES e where DEP_ID != <Departments under particular manager>
```

Now the result will the list of employees's first name not under that manager

Comment: @FaroukDouglas . . . This answer is simply not correct.